# Data Validation pointing to source cell

Tags: validation, excel, compare, excel-2003, vba

I have data validation in use within Column A, where if duplicate data is entered an error message appears. It just shows the error but doesn't tell me where in the column the data is.

What I am wanting to know is it possible for Excel to navigate to the source cell, where the duplicate value is being compared against?

If Cell A2 = 12345 and I attempt to update A50 = 12345, Excel produces an error message but is it possible for it to point my cursor to Cell A2, as that is where the compared data is?

Comment: Could you include the data validation formula you are using for column A?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same task in & out. My solution is to have

1. a generic dupe check routine receiving two ranges (targetcell, datarange)
2. a `WorkSheet_Change()` event firing the dupe check for columns I want it to
3. a cell in the header of the sheet for error message output

**example:**

I've extracted the significant parts of one of them ...

Let's start with `DupeCheck()` ... it's running through a range (`DataRange`) and returning the first cell which has the same value than the `Target` to be tested. This function resides in a module of its own. Like this it can be used by multiple sheets within the same workbook.

```
Function DupeCheck(Target As Range, DataRange As Range) As Range
Dim DataCell As Range

    Set DupeCheck = Nothing

    ' compare each cell of DataRange with Target
    For Each DataCell In DataRange.Cells

        ' exclude Target which may be part of DataRange per se
        If Intersect(DataCell, Target) Is Nothing Then
            If DataCell = Target Then

                ' duplicate found ... terminate on first find
                Set DupeCheck = DataCell
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next DataCell
End Function
```

Now let's look at the `Worksheet_Change` event, which resides in the code area of the sheet it acts on. In my case I have plenty of validations, but I reduced the example to include only relevant code ... here we check if the cell change applies to column A, in which case we fire the `DupeCheck()` function and, depending of the return, set or clear an error message into a cell on the worksheet named [ErrorMessage] ... here we of course could as well position the cursor into the duplicate cell (e.g. `TempR.Select` ... matter of taste)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim TempR As Range

' various validations
' always break on first error found
' output to named range ErrorMessage

    ' Dupe Check for PoP ID (column A)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        Set TempR = DupeCheck(Target, Range("A1:A50"))

        If Not TempR Is Nothing Then
            [ErrorMessage] = "Duplicate ID in " & TempR.AddressLocal
        Else
            [ErrorMessage] = ""
        End If

    ' ElseIf Target.Column = 4 Then ' other validations (deleted)
    ' ....

    End If

End Sub
```

et voilà

Comment: Hi Mike, please excuse my ignorance. But I don't fully understand your answer. I'm not entirely clued up on Excel, as I have limited experience and have been using tutorials to get to the stage I am at. Again apologies for not understanding your answer.

Comment: sorry ... maybe I took the presence of [excel-vba] too literal ... my suggestion goes into the direction of writing some pieces of VBA code

Comment: I see, if you're happy to advise how I should go about it. I know how to input the vba code to a worksheet, however programming is not my forte. However i am willing to learn as i suspect it is a good skill to attain.

Comment: added example as a head start ... let me know if/how you're developing it into your own solution

Comment: Hi Mike, I will give this a go and incorporate it into my file. You have been a great help so far, so thank you for that. I will attach a screenshot of my worksheet if it helps you understand the idea behind what it is I'm working with.

Comment: Also Mike to help, the data in Column A is coming from a Barcode scan, if that changes the code in anyway, apologies for not mentioning this earlier. I have successfully made the data from the scan appear in the selected cell, in Column A, but i am having to click the next free cell manually for the data not to overwrite the previous.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have uploaded the file on OneDrive, please see this link. http://1drv.ms/1MGef2S , also i fully understand if my asking you of this is unacceptable, apologies for this again.

Comment: Barcode reader doesn't make a difference ... it's the same as using the keyboard. Problem is that barcode readers often don't send CR+LF at the end of a scan that's why you have to press [ENTER] manually. Try to see if the reader can be configured to add CR+LF. The `Worksheet_Change()` is triggered by CR+LF (or Tab or clicking a different cell with mouse)

Comment: Hi Mike, I will check manufacturers documentation and will reply with findings. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Mike, Carriage Return is part of the default programming for my Datalogic Scanner, thankfully. I am having an issue incorporating your code into my File. I added the Worksheet Change in the Worksheet Code, and the DupeCheck in the Workbook Code. But whenever i scan anything, including unique barcodes, the data appears in the Cell but i get a "Compile Error" with DupCheck highlighted and "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" highlighted in yellow, in the Worksheet Code. I suspect it doesn't know where to get the value from. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: create an individual module (VBA window: insert / module) for the DupeCheck function ... check spelling (Dup vs. DupE)

Comment: Hi Mike, I have done as you have suggested. But now, when i enter a duplicate value I am getting a "Runtime Error: Object required" with [ErrorMessage] highlighted in yellow under "If Not TempR Is Nothing Then" within the Worksheet_Change. Sorry for the bother.